# Upload user profile images from desktop to sharepoint using a windows service

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2013

All,

I have this question posted on sharepoint.stachexchange.com too. I am sharepoint newbie and just started working on Sharepoint 2013. My task is to upload and set user profile images which are saved in a local disk (share folder). All the images are named as .jpg. I have written a windows service to check the directory and move all user images to associated account on the Microsoft exchange server. My next challenge is to move it to users on sharepoint. Is it possible to pull it from the exchange server? Or is there a powershell script that can help me move the same image to sharepoint too ?  Any help is highly appreciated. Since I have no experience I am not sure where to start.

Thank you

Comment: Can't you just enable the AD sync? I'm 99% certain that Exchange stores the images in AD. And SP can also sync pictures from AD, so .....

Comment: Thank you Frode. I was not sure there was an option like that. I am very new to sharepoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there were some changes from 2010 to 2013, for the better.  Here is a blog post on this topic:

http://richardstk.com/2013/04/12/import-user-photos-from-active-directory-into-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: The link is very informative. I will have a look and update the post if I can get it to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that SharePoint 2013 uses a larger photo than SharePoint 2010. Thumbnails imported from Active Directory are blown up in 2013 and look blurry.

Here is an article regarding a powershell script that can mass import photos from a directory: 
http://get-spscripts.com/2010/12/upload-multiple-user-profile.html

IT does not work if you have underscores in your user names but otherwise it should work.